# How to create global session variables in express

Tags: node.js, express, session-state

I am making a quiz app and I have these global variables x, score, and difficulty out of which i am using x to fetch question from my database through serial number(sno). Everything worked fine until i deployed the app to heroku and asked my friends to visit at the same time. I leant that in node multiple requests do not have different values of variables but the same. My question is how do i define them independently for each session?

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser")
var session = require('express-session');

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

var x = 1;
var score = 0;
var difficulty = "";

//APP CONFIG
mongoose.connect(MONGO_URI, {useNewUrlParser: true});
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(session({secret: 'keyboard cat', saveUninitialized: true, resave: true, cookie: { secure: true }}));

//MODEL CONFIG
var questionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    difficulty: String,
    sno: Number,
    question: String,
    option1: String,
    option2: String,
    option3: String,
    option4: String,
    answer: String
});

var Question = mongoose.model("Question", questionSchema);

app.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.render("home")
})

app.post("/", function(req, res){
    difficulty = req.body.difficulty;
    res.redirect("/startQuiz")
})

app.get("/startQuiz", function(req, res){
    if(x>10){
        res.render("score", {score: score})
        x = 1;
        score = 0;
    } else{
        Question.findOne({difficulty: difficulty, sno: x}, function(err, question){
            if(err){
                console.log(err)
            } else {
                res.render("index", {question: question});
            }
        });
    }
});

app.post("/startQuiz", function(req, res) {
    Question.findOne({difficulty: difficulty, sno: x}, function(err,foundQuestion){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        } else{
            if(foundQuestion.answer === req.body.val){
                score++;
                x++;
                res.send("#7fce44")
            } else {
                x++;
                res.send("#e80909")
            }
        }
    })
});


app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log(`Our app is running on port ${ PORT }`);
});
```

Comment: You could move all global variables into user session variables(req.session). Because all global variable shared between multiple users.

Comment: Could you explain that a bit more? I have the same problem and don't know how to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `session` to store variables. And middleware to set it for each request.

```
// Run a "middleware" function on each request
app.use((req, res, next) => {
   // Check if we've already initialised a session
   if (!req.session.initialised) {
      // Initialise our variables on the session object (that's persisted across requests by the same user
      req.session.initialised = true;
      req.session.x = 1;
      req.session.score = 0;
      req.session.difficulty = '';
   }
   next();
});
```

Elsewhere you can then access them through the session again.

```
pp.get("/startQuiz", function(req, res){
    if(req.session.x > 10){
        ...
```

To update the values simply update he desired req.session value in your function. Like:
`req.session.score = 4`
or
`req.session.diffculty = 'hard'`

Comment: Can you tell me what the first segment of code you provided does? i added the changes you suggested and my browser just keeps loading

Comment: the values are not getting updated in different functions, any workaround?

Comment: How many nodes are you serving it on within Heroku? Is it working locally with the session changes?

Comment: The value of difficulty is updated on "/" route but on "/startQuiz" its still an empty string, i console logged to find this

Comment: You have `secure: true` set for your session cookie. which wont work for your local development. you'll get a new session each request